# Struts 2 client side validation only works when `devMode=true`

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to use client side validation using Struts 2 (2.3.34), but the problem is that the javascript validation code is completelly generated only when `devMode=true`. I'm using the xhtml theme.

When `devMode=false` it just generates the `getFieldValue` function then returns:

Reading the `form-close-validate.ftl` file, it seems the 'tagNames' list or the 'validators' list are empty?

See: [form-close-validate frament](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/0314ddcb5c8badb8c216735f318fe75ffe56d6b5/core/src/main/resources/template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl#L65)

My form:

```
<s:form action="empleado_editsave" method="POST" name="empForm" namespace="/admin" theme="xhtml" validate="true" id="formEmpleadoEdit">
...
</s:form>
```

EDIT: found a workaround with `devMode=false` and `reloadXmlConfiguration=true`, however it is still far from ideal.

EDIT2: with `reloadXmlConfiguration=false` it generates the following js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm_formEmpleadoEdit() {
        var getFieldValue = function(field) {
            var type = field.type ? field.type : field[0].type;
            if (type == 'select-one' || type == 'select-multiple') {
                return (field.selectedIndex == -1 ? "" : field.options[field.selectedIndex].value);
            } else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio') {
                if (!field.length) {
                    field = [field];
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                    if (field[i].checked) {
                        return field[i].value;
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }
            return field.value;
        }
        form = document.getElementById("formEmpleadoEdit");
        clearErrorMessages(form);
        clearErrorLabels(form);

        var errors = false;
        var continueValidation = true;

        return !errors;
    }
</script>
```

with `reloadXmlConfiguration=true` it generates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm_formEmpleadoEdit() {
        var getFieldValue = function(field) {
            var type = field.type ? field.type : field[0].type;
            if (type == 'select-one' || type == 'select-multiple') {
                return (field.selectedIndex == -1 ? "" : field.options[field.selectedIndex].value);
            } else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio') {
                if (!field.length) {
                    field = [field];
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                    if (field[i].checked) {
                        return field[i].value;
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }
            return field.value;
        }
        form = document.getElementById("formEmpleadoEdit");
        clearErrorMessages(form);
        clearErrorLabels(form);

        var errors = false;
        var continueValidation = true;
        // field name: empleado.legajo
        // validator name: required
        if (form.elements['empleado.legajo']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.legajo'];

            var error = "El legajo es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (fieldValue == "") {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.legajo
        // validator name: int
        if (form.elements['empleado.legajo']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.legajo'];

            var error = "El legajo es inválido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null) {
                if (parseInt(fieldValue) <
                     1 ||
                        false) {
                    addError(field, error);
                    errors = true;

                }
            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.nombre
        // validator name: requiredstring
        if (form.elements['empleado.nombre']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.nombre'];

            var error = "El nombre es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && (fieldValue == "" || fieldValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length == 0)) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.apellido
        // validator name: requiredstring
        if (form.elements['empleado.apellido']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.apellido'];

            var error = "El apellido es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && (fieldValue == "" || fieldValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length == 0)) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.telefonos
        // validator name: requiredstring
        if (form.elements['empleado.telefonos']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.telefonos'];

            var error = "El teléfono es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && (fieldValue == "" || fieldValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length == 0)) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.horaentrada
        // validator name: requiredstring
        if (form.elements['empleado.horaentrada']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.horaentrada'];

            var error = "El horario de entrada es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && (fieldValue == "" || fieldValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length == 0)) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.horaentrada
        // validator name: regex
        if (form.elements['empleado.horaentrada']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.horaentrada'];

            var error = "El horario de entrada es inválido. Use el formato HH:MM";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && !fieldValue.match("^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.horasalida
        // validator name: requiredstring
        if (form.elements['empleado.horasalida']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.horasalida'];

            var error = "El horario de salida es requerido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && (fieldValue == "" || fieldValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length == 0)) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.horasalida
        // validator name: regex
        if (form.elements['empleado.horasalida']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.horasalida'];

            var error = "El horario de salida es inválido. Use el formato HH:MM";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && !fieldValue.match("^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.fechaNacim
        // validator name: date
        if (form.elements['empleado.fechaNacim']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.fechaNacim'];

            var error = "La fecha de nacimiento debe ser mayor a 01/01/10";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

        }
        // field name: empleado.email
        // validator name: email
        if (form.elements['empleado.email']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.email'];

            var error = "El e-mail es inválido";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && fieldValue.length > 0 && fieldValue.match("\\b^[\'_a-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[\'_a-z0-9-\\+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,6})$\\b")==null) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.posicion.posicionId
        // validator name: required
        if (form.elements['empleado.posicion.posicionId']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.posicion.posicionId'];

            var error = "La posición es requerida";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (fieldValue == "") {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: empleado.posicion.posicionId
        // validator name: regex
        if (form.elements['empleado.posicion.posicionId']) {
            field = form.elements['empleado.posicion.posicionId'];

            var error = "La posición es inválida";
            var fieldValue = getFieldValue(field);

            if (continueValidation && fieldValue != null && !fieldValue.match("^[1-9]\\d*$")) {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }

        return !errors;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't make any sense. the client side validation has been made with struts tags long time ago, also tagging generates some javascript that is missing in your question.

Comment: @RomanC added EDIT2 to the question that shows the generated JS.

Comment: Looks like you missing some code generation from the ftl itself that is missing.

Comment: Do you use `<s:head>`?

Comment: I was using `<sx:head>` sin I was mixing both standard and dojo components in the form. Anyway I gived up with this approach.

Comment: struts dojo plugin is deprecated years ago.